# Choppy moving object Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Ok so i don't usually do much with javascript and i have seen other issues similar to this one on here but they don't seem to be working for me. I am using this code and have an issue. When my circle/ball moves it is really choppy like as if the frames are spread apart or there is a slow refresh rate. Im trying to make it a really smooth moving ball. Any help here would be appreciated.

```
<script>
    var context;
    var x=100;
    var y=200;
    var dx=5;
    var dy=5;

    function init() {
        context= circleCanvas.getContext('2d');
        setInterval(draw,300);
    }

    function draw() {

        context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
        // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
        context.arc(x,y,40,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();

        // Boundary Logic
        if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx;
        if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy;
        x+=dx;
        y+=dy;
    }
</script>

<body onload="init()">
    <%= render "layouts/header"%>
    <%= yield %>
    <canvas id="circleCanvas", width="1000", height="1000">
    </canvas>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

The time is 300ms between frame compared to 16.7ms (60 fps) or 33.4ms (30 fps). Also, don't use setInterval/setTimeout to animate - they are very inaccurate, cannot use fractional values and are unable to sync to monitor updates.

`requestAnimationFrame` will give you perfect sync and timing - a small modification should get you there. Use instead small step values (dx/dy) to adjust speed.

```
function init() {
    context= circleCanvas.getContext('2d');
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);              // start, see below
}

function draw() {

    context.clearRect(0,0,300,300);
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)";
    // Draws a circle of radius 20 at the coordinates 100,100 on the canvas
    context.arc(x,y,40,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    context.closePath();
    context.fill();

    // Boundary Logic
    if( x<0 || x>300) dx=-dx;
    if( y<0 || y>300) dy=-dy;
    x+=dx;
    y+=dy;

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);    // loop here
}
```

Tip: `fillStyle` can be expensive. If color doesn't change just set it once outside the loop. `closePath()` is not necessary with `fill()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your interval to something smaller; with a delta of 5 pixels and a 300ms interval, it does move pretty slow (only 15pixels per second). I tried 10ms first and it went crazy!

```
function init() {
    context= circleCanvas.getContext('2d');
    setInterval(draw,20);
}
```

Comment: the speed isn't the issue. I purposely want it to move slow. I just want it to move slow and smooth if that makes sense?

Comment: Got it. It looks like K3N is on the right track with what you actually need.